# What's the most efficient way to run over a Cursor in Android?

Tags: android

Is there a faster way than calling moveToNext in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the only method Cursor has got... it also has other similar methods but they too will do the same.. you cannot give your own way to traverse through it.. its APK level. need to follow it..

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the Cursor [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) there are only limited methods available to run through a cursor.

The only thing that could save some iterations of your loop is the [moveToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition%28int%29) method.
If you know that say the next 30 entries are not of interest you could jump ahead a bunch of positions. The real question is why are you running through the pointer?
If you query a Database and want to find a specific entry in the resulting cursors maybe you can narrow down the number of results with a more specific query.